# What does a Partial Copy Sandbox actually copy from Production?

Tags: sandbox, partial-sandbox

Related to this question:

[Partial Copy Sandbox help required](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220118/partial-copy-sandbox-help-required)

Will this bring a random selection of the data across for each object I select? Can I exclude the record data on an object or would I have to just delete it using dataloader?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127753/can-i-choose-which-records-are-copied-in-a-partial-copy-sandbox?rq=1

Comment: There is a help article here explaining that it is a randomized choice unless it is a M: D relationship: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206556&type=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Partial copy sandbox just now to verify all details. First you define a Sandbox template, in which you select Objects whose data you want to copy into the sandbox, **If data is less than 10000 records it copies whole data.**

If data is more than 10000 records i assume it copies any 10000 records.(As in my production there was only limited data).

Reference:
[What is the purpose of 3 different types of Sandboxes that we have ?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hUbuAAE)